# Rake "no such file to load -- java" even when `which ruby` -> jruby

Tags: rake, jruby

I am a Ruby noob (rube?) and am having trouble configuring my environment to get `rake` to build something with a Java dependency.

I run

```
$ PATH=/tmp/jruby-dodge:"$PATH" rake
```

and get

> ```
> /opt/local/bin/ruby -S rspec spec/contextual_spec.rb
> /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- java (LoadError)
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>         from /Users/msamuel/work/igrigorik/contextual/lib/contextual/contextual.rb:1
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>         from /Users/msamuel/work/igrigorik/contextual/lib/contextual.rb:2
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
>         from /Users/msamuel/work/igrigorik/contextual/spec/contextual_spec.rb:1
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
>         from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
>         from /opt/local/bin/rspec:19
> rake aborted!
> /opt/local/bin/ruby -S rspec spec/contextual_spec.rb failed
>
> Tasks: TOP => default => spec
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)
> ```

The `PATH=/tmp/jruby-dodge:...` makes sure that `which ruby` actually resolves to a symlink to `/opt/local/bin/jruby`.

Is "no such file to load -- java" related to jruby at all?  `java -version` emits `java version "1.6.0_29"` so I don't think there is a failure to start up a JVM.

When using `rake` to build something with Java dependencies for use under jruby, does it matter whether `rake` is running under jruby or ruby?  If so, how do I specify that?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `rvm` lets me juggle multiple rubies.

[Installing RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) explains how to install it.

```
rvm install jruby
```

makes sure `rvm` knows about jruby.

```
rvm use jruby
```

updates the environment so that `ruby` means `jruby`.

Gems seem to be installed per-flavor of ruby.